# IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query

Tags: android

```
 protected void onPreExecute()
                {
                    super.onPreExecute();               
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Fetching", "Fetching Contacts", true, false);
                }

                @Override


                protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://mythreeg.dyndns.org:8088/WcfService_Officetail/WcfDataService.svc/VW_CONTACTS()/?$filter=mobile ne null");

                List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("VW_CONTACTS").execute().toList();

                System.out.println("Size - " + listEntities.size());



                    for (OEntity entity : listEntities) {

                        categories.add((String) entity.getProperty("contact_name").getValue() + (String) entity.getProperty("mobile").getValue());

                    }
```

Error:

```
    02-15 13:26:26.260: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 102:
     http://mythreeg.dyndns.org:8088/WcfService_Officetail/WcfDataService.svc/VW_CONTACTS()/?$filter=mobile ne null/$metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Please  try below URL it's work here

mythreeg.dyndns.org:8088/WcfService_Officetail/WcfDataService.svc/VW_CONTACTS/?$filter=mobile%20ne%20null

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Encoder and URL.Decoder to solve the problem regarding illegal argument Ecxeption regarding special character used in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url="http://mythreeg.dyndns.org:8088/WcfService_Officetail/WcfDataService.svc/VW_CONTACTS()/?$filter=mobile ne null";
url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create(url);
```

Just replace the space with %20 it works for me